# Asp.net web form migration to dot net core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, webforms

I have an application in asp.net 2.0 web forms.
I want to migrate it to Asp.net core web forms.
Is it feasible?
I did not see any link on internet for migration of web forms.
Please provide any link or insight for this.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Core doesn't have a web forms part. It's an old model and won't be includeded in the ASP.NET Core according to Microsoft. The new and recommended model is MVC. There is no interoperability between them, because they have a differt architechture and behavior.

You have two opportunities. First: you don't migrate, everything will work as it has been. Second: you re-implement your solution with ASP.NET Core and with MVC architecture.

Comment: I have gone through Asp.net core 2.0 . They have razor pages app there. So I think it's better to migrate web form to razor page app rather than complete MVC .Do you have any suggestions

Comment: Razor Pages are for easy, not so complex business applications, where you don't want to use a big MVC infrastructure, but you need some server logic. If your application is complex and you use event handlers in the page's code files, then move to MVC. Otherwise, you can give a try with Razor Pages and you will see in the beginning if it's worth to "migrate" to it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [DotVVM](https://github.com/riganti/dotvvm)?

It is not Web Forms on .NET Core, but:

- many concepts in DotVVM are similar to ASP.NET Web Forms (postbacks, server controls, master pages, even the names of the controls and page lifecycle events)
- it is easy to learn for ASP.NET Web Forms developers
- no cryptic viewstate hidden field
- the controls don't produce ugly HTML
- the MVVM pattern is used
- no need to know or write JavaScript - C#, HTML and CSS is enough to start coding
- DotVVM supports both .NET Core and full .NET Framework
- can be added to existing ASP.NET Web Forms or MVC applications on .NET Framework
- DotVVM is open source
- Visual Studio extension with IntelliSense and project templates

Disclaimer: taken from https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1961#issuecomment-323698018

Answer (score 0):

There are some useful resources I'd like to share with the StackOverflow community just in case you are having troubles to decide what to do:

- modernization of your existing Web Forms app
- migration to MVC or Core
- or whether to start a new project on Web Forms, MVC and Core.

Here you go:

- Modernizing ASP.NET Web Forms Applications by Tomáš Herceg (Microsoft MVP ) - https://tomasherceg.com/blog/post/modernizing-asp-net-web-forms-applications-part-1
- Migrating Old ASP.NET Applications to .NET Core by Edi Wang (Microsoft MVP) - https://edi.wang/post/2018/10/31/migrating-old-aspnet-applications-to-net-core
- Choose between ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core (Microsoft docs) - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/choose-aspnet-framework?view=aspnetcore-3.1 - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/proper-to-2x/?view=aspnetcore-3.1
- Migrate from ASP.NET to ASP.NET Core (Microsoft docs) - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/proper-to-2x/?view=aspnetcore-3.1
- https://www.telerik.com/blogs/review-of-telerik-toolsets-for-aspnet-web-forms-core